# Slow User Interface in Microsoft Test Manager 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Has anyone else experienced problems with the speed of the UI when using Microsoft Test Manager 2010?  Most of the time when typing it is extremely slow, and after adding a step and pressing enter it takes anywhere from 10 to 20 seconds to complete saving the step and moving to the next one.  A co-worker of mine has the same problem.  It also seems to crash randomly.  However sometimes the program runs at a reasonably decent speed.

Visual Studio 2010 runs fine on my machine and other WPF applications work great.

I am using Windows XP SP3, 2GB RAM, 3.4GHZ

Answer (score 1):

The performance is not so good in Microsoft Test Manager because it does a lot of things in the background.

2 ways to speed up things:

1. Close all other applications during recording (they affect the recording a lot)
2. Disable all trace output listeners that you don't need (e.g. System information is not very helpful)